# KeyError on a certain word

Tags: python, nlp, text-classification, naivebayes, non-english

I am trying to use Naive Bayes for spam-ham classification.

```
training_set['E_Mail'] = training_set['E_Mail'].str.split()
vocabulary = []
for email in training_set['E_Mail']:
 for word in email:
     vocabulary.append(tuple(word))

vocabulary = list(set(vocabulary))


word_counts_per_email = {unique_word: [0] * len(training_set['E_Mail']) for unique_word in vocabulary}

for index, email in enumerate(training_set['E_Mail']):
 for word in email:
   word_counts_per_email[word][index] += 1
```

I am getting a word error repeteadly on here:

```
word_counts_per_email = {unique_word: [0] * len(training_set['E_Mail']) for unique_word in vocabulary}

for index, email in enumerate(training_set['E_Mail']):
 for word in email:
   word_counts_per_email[word][index] += 1
```

The error message is just this:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-30-1706354aaff0> in <module>()
     3 for index, email in enumerate(training_set['E_Mail']):
     4   for word in email:
----> 5     word_counts_per_email[word][index] += 1

KeyError: 'hafta'
```

'hafta' is the first word of the pandas dataframe and the trainng dataset.

I tried the solution on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46614713/keyerror-on-the-same-word) issue that seemed similar to mine but it didn't work out.

I will appreciate any hint to get this over, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that this line `vocabulary.append(tuple(word))` should be changed to `vocabulary.append(word)` since your version might put letters instead of words into `vocabulary` and therefore `word_counts_per_email`.

In case this doesn't work, I suggest looking into contents of `vocabulary`/ `word_counts_per_email` so you can determine what went wrong.

Comment: Thank you so much for the quick help, I didn't expect to get an answer this soon and it worked out great! I overlooked that part and focused on the other parts... Thanks and I hope things go well for you!!